# Are there any possible way to use two channels of flutter

Tags: flutter

I just want to use `origin` channel, for my flutter-web development. But also I need `stable` channel for few applications which I created before.

I want to know are there any possibilities to use both, without switching channels every time in command line like,

```
flutter channel origin
flutter upgrade
```

Any help or suggestions would be great.

Comment: cannot you just change `PATH` environment variable?

Comment: @pskink can you please elaborate your suggestion a bit?

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#update-your-path

Comment: @pskink installing two flutter in different locations and changing `PATH` would do the trick it seems. I ll try it out and see. thanks anyway

Comment: You can see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66224133/12118935